# Cual es la manera correcta de insertar datos mediante JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Cual de las siguientes maneras el la correcta o mejor al insertar datos mediante JavaScript a un archivo html.

**Archivo Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="primer_div">

    </div>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Por un lado creo e inserto mediante createElement y appendChild

```
var div = document.getElementById('primer_div');

let ul=document.createElement('ul');
let li=document.createElement('li');
li.className = "list-group-item";

let button=document.createElement('button');
button.textContent="Presiona";

li.appendChild(button)
ul.appendChild(li);
div.appendChild(ul);
```

Y de otra forma mediante innerHtml o text con témplate string

```
div.innerHTML= 
    `
    <ul> 
        <li class = "list-group-item"> 
            <button> Presiona </button>
        </li> 
    </ul>
    `
```

De las dos maneras se llegan al mismo resultado.
A mi parecer veo un código mas limpio y ordenado utilizando el primer ejemplo, pero me gustaría saber pro y contras de ambos casos

Comment: Tu pregunta es basada en opiniones. Para nadie es un secreto que usar `innerHTML` es más costoso en términos de *performance*, ya que implica recrear todos los nodos dentro del elemento al cual le aplicas dicha propiedad. Por otro lado, usar `createElement / appendChild` tiene sus desventajas en cuanto a la legibilidad y cuando deseamos realizar múltiples cosas con el elemento, por ejemplo insertar iterativamente elementos de una lista, lo que implica un recálculo de los estilos y volver a renderizar el contenido en cada iteración. Por lo tanto la respuesta a tu pregunta es **depende**.